# How to store data into array after editing jTable

Tags: java

I am developing a program. In this program I want to let the user to edit the `jtable`(table has two column and user enter the data into second column). After that I want to store that edited data into integer type array(in this case I want to store second column data only).

`getvalue` button code looks like below.

```
private void btntablesubmitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    int[] btime = new int[this.noofprocess];
    tablebursttime.getModel();

    for(int i=1; i <=this.noofprocess;i++){
        btime[i] = Integer.parseInt( model.getValueAt(i,1).toString() );
        System.out.println(btime[i]);
    }
}
```

When I run this program with above code, there are some errors.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
at roundrobin.RoundRobinAlgorithm.btntablesubmitMouseClicked(RoundRobinAlgorithm.java:579)
at roundrobin.RoundRobinAlgorithm.access$1000(RoundRobinAlgorithm.java:17)
at roundrobin.RoundRobinAlgorithm$10.mouseClicked(RoundRobinAlgorithm.java:363)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

How do I prevent this error?

Comment: `i <=this.noofprocess` 

Comment: i try it but didn't work

Comment: Hint - Java is `0` indexed, you are reading from `1` to `noofprocess` is overrunning the end of the array

Comment: Are there two columns in the table or are there three columns: `model.getValueAt(i, 2)`.

Comment: table has two columns

Comment: Not according to the arguments you placed into the **DefaultTableModel#getValueAt()** method.

Comment: i changed  getValueAt(i,2) to getValueAt(i,1) then i run the program....now show this error message " Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0""

Comment: Did you follow @DarkKnight's answer as well?

Comment: yes didn't work........shall i put the jtable edit enable code also?

Answer (score 0):

Change `for(int i=1; i <=this.noofprocess;i++){` to `for(int i=0; i <this.noofprocess;i++){`, reason is indexes are `0` based and size of collection starts with `1`.

Comment: i try it....now appear this error message      "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0"

Answer (score 0):

your Exception is coming from here

```
Integer.parseInt( model.getValueAt(i,2).toString() );
```

try to change your model object creation like below

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tablebursttime.getModel();
```

**Update**

Try This

```
private void btntablesubmitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tablebursttime.getModel();
    int[] btime = new int[this.noofprocess];

    for(int i=0; i <this.noofprocess;i++){
        btime[i] = Integer.parseInt( model.getValueAt(i+1,1).toString() );
        System.out.println(btime[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i follow your guide now it show this error  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i <this.noofprocess;i++){
            btime[i] = Integer.parseInt( model.getValueAt(i,1).toString() );
            System.out.println(btime[i]);
        }
```

Value at (i,2) doesn't exist for 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the `JTable`'s model, and you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Try this:

```
private void btntablesubmitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    TableModel model = tablebursttime.getModel();
    int[] btime = new int[this.noofprocess];

    for(int i=1; i <=this.noofprocess;i++){
        btime[i-1] = Integer.parseInt( model.getValueAt(i,1).toString() );
        System.out.println(btime[i-1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initialisation of `model` is also the cause for the error. You should rather have `DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tablebursttime.getModel()`. You can also add `stopCellEditing()` to prevent a possible nullReference while the last cell of column 2 has focus.

```
tablebursttime.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tablebursttime.getModel();
    int[] btime = new int[this.noofprocess]; 
    for(int i=0; i <this.noofprocess;i++){
        btime[i] = Integer.parseInt(model.getValueAt(i,1).toString() );
        System.out.println(btime[i]);
    }
```